# Gnuplot: Combined Histogram Clustered

Tags: plot, gnuplot, histogram

I have 2 separate `histogram clustered` plots whose `x-axis` is the same and the bars are also same, but `y-axis` is different.

I want to represent the combined information from these 2 plots in a single plot. One way to do this is to assign the `y-axis` of the second plot as `z-axis`. I have attached a rough example here:

[image]

Questions:

1. Is there a simple way to do this in `gnuplot`?
2. Are there better ways of combining such information from two plots together?

Comment: see [gnuplot samples](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/layout.html), here in particular the 4th one (auto-layout of stacked plots) for your 2nd question. I think the answer to the 1st question is "no".

Comment: Take a look at the [histogram samples](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html).  Look at the 7th example with the side-by-side histogram for Northern Europe, Southern Europe, and the British Isles.  Would something like that be acceptable?  The x-axis won't be shared, but each histogram will occur side by side in the same plot with its own xlabels (as in the example).  It is possible to have the second histogram use the y2 axis, so it doesn't mess up the range of the first histogram.

Comment: Also, look at the example mentioned by @vaettchen .  It is possible to line up histograms like that, and even have only one key if desired.